# Firebase FCM delayed delivery with Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-functions

The idea that I have a client which app use Firebase as a backend, and so he wants to send notification after order were created and order's state hasn't changed in 5 minutes.

So it looks like:
Order Created -> State hasn't changed in 5 minutes -> Notification sent.

Any ideas how to make it possible?

Comment: Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you can do is listen to item created, which is easy to do. Then use NodeJS equivalent of Handler.postDelayed() to get value and see if its changed and then send notification. I am sorry I am not proficient enough in JS to show you the syntax. There should be something of that sort as JS is most used language.